# Google cloud transfer service costs

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloud, transfer

The costs to transfer data between regional standard bucket to regional nearline bucket (as backup) using the cloud storage transfer service is unclear because we don't know which operations the transfer job will execute in the background.

For example:

Regional standard buckets contains 100000 files in 1000 dirs and the total size is 1GB.

- 100 x class A `storage.objects.list` = 100/10000 x 0,05$ = 0,0005$
- 100000 x class B `storage.*.get` = 100000/10000 x 0,004$  = 0,04$

If target is empty, regional nearline bucket:

- 100000 x class A `storage.*.insert` = 100000/10000 x 0,1$= 1$
- 1GB x 0,013$/GB/month nearline storage = 0,013$

Will the count of operations be reduced if there is already some data in the target bucket?

thanks in advance,
noirabys

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Cloud Storage to Cloud Storage transfer pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/pricing#bucket-to-bucket), Storage Transfer Service uses [`rewrite`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite) operations to move data between Cloud Storage buckets and it's a Class A operation. As it rewrites objects, it doesn't look like the number of operations is going to be reduced if some data is already in the target bucket.

As the [Operations pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) mentions,

> When changing the storage class of an object, either yourself or with
> Object Lifecycle Management, the Class A rate associated with the
> object's destination storage class applies. For example, changing
> 1,000 objects from Standard Storage to Coldline Storage counts as
> 1,000 Class A operations and is billed at the Class A operations rate
> for Coldline Storage.

So if you transfer an object from a standard bucket to a nearline bucket, it's going to be calculated as a class A operation on a Nearline bucket.

Comment: thanks @Farid Shumbar 
it is a good hint. Does it mean that transferal of one file is one class a operation if storage classes are the same? what if storage class in source is standard and in sink is nearline?

Comment: @Noirabys I've updated my answer, please review.